# How to clean up partitions after OS X is moved from HD to SSD

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, recovery

Yesterday an *Apple Certified Macintosh Technician* installed an SSD into my iMac medio 2011. The iMac was born with an 1TB HDD but now a Crucial M4 SSD is also installed inside the mac. I've moved my OS X to the SSD using the [OS X Recovery](http://www.apple.com/macosx/recovery/), where the OS was installed using an Time Capsule Backup. Afterwards I did an *Erase* of the old HDD in *Disk Utility* to remove my old OS and my data has now been transferred to new, clean partition. Afterwards I inserted my Lion DVD and did an reinstall of the OS X to get the OS X Recovery partition created on my SSD. The name of the partition on the SSD is *Crucial M4 SSD* and the name of partition on my old 1TB HDD is *Storage*.

Please see this output from *diskutil list*:

```
iMac:~ dennis$ diskutil list/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Crucial M4 SSD          255.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         999.9 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Storage                *999.7 GB   disk3
```

1. Why do I have an Apple_Boot on disk1 after the entire disk was erased?
2. What is the EFI and Apple_Boot?
3. Is it normal that the type of the *Recovery HD* is Apple_Boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I have an Apple_Boot on disk1 after the entire disk was erased?

I am not sure on this one. Seeing the size (134 MB) I don' this this is the actual boot partition itself.

-

> What is the EFI and Apple_Boot?

EFI is the [Extensible Firmware Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) system partition. This is a special partition that holds boot loaders for all the OSes installed, in other partitions:

> The EFI System partition is a partition on a data storage device that
>   is used by machines that adhere to the Extensible Firmware Interface.
>   It contains the boot loader programs for all operating systems
>   installed (in other partitions) on the device, device driver files
>   (used by the firmware at boot time) for other devices, and system
>   utility programs that are intended to be run before an operating
>   system is booted.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)

-

> Is it normal that the type of the Recovery HD is Apple_Boot?*

Yes. Otherwise you cannot use the recovery partition to *recover* when the OS on the other partition(s) has crashed, right?

The recovery partition is actually replacement of the OS install disk. 
[From OS X Lion: About Lion Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718)

> OS X Lion includes a new feature called Lion Recovery that includes
>   all of the tools you need to reinstall Lion, repair your disk, and
>   even restore from a Time Machine backup without the need for optical
>   discs.

Comment: So your conclusion is that every thing except from * disk1s3* is perfect? Is there any chance that I can remove the *disk1s3* without having to erase the entire disk?